# Carousel Background colour

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im using Bootstrap 5, along with visual studio code to design a website. I have added a carousel into the landing page, and it works perfectly. The only problem i have is that the backgorund colour is stuck at dark grey and I need to change it to white. I have tried surrounding it with a div and changing the background colour, and also referencing the carousel class in ccs and changing the backgorund colour there also but have not gotten any luck. Please see below the HTML markup, detailing the carousel, along with the CCS that I've used to style it with. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Many thanks!

```
   <div class="carouselSize">

<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-indicators">
      <button type="button" data-bs-target="#myCarousel" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
      <button type="button" data-bs-target="#myCarousel" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
      <button type="button" data-bs-target="#myCarousel" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <svg class="bd-placeholder-img" width="100%" height="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" aria-hidden="true" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false"><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#777"/></svg>

        <div class="container">
          <div class="carousel-caption text-start">
              <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/05/28/16/37/sport-788105_960_720.jpg" width="575px">
            <h1>Example headline.</h1>
            <p>Some representative placeholder content for the first slide of the carousel.</p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#">Sign up today</a></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <svg class="bd-placeholder-img" width="100%" height="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" aria-hidden="true" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false"><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#777"/></svg>

        <div class="container">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h1>Another example headline.</h1>
            <p>Some representative placeholder content for the second slide of the carousel.</p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#">Learn more</a></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <svg class="bd-placeholder-img" width="100%" height="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" aria-hidden="true" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false"><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#777"/></svg>

        <div class="container">
          <div class="carousel-caption text-end">
            <h1>One more for good measure.</h1>
            <p>Some representative placeholder content for the third slide of this carousel.</p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#">Browse gallery</a></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#myCarousel" data-bs-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
    </button>
    <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#myCarousel" data-bs-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
.carousel-item{
    height: 32rem;
    background: white;
     position: relative;
}
.container {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}
```

Comment: find <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="777"/> and replace it with <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="white"/>

Comment: thanks! how would i then change the colour of the previous and next buttons? as they are also white and disappear when the fill is changed to white. many thanks"!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to original question: find

```
<rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="777"/>
```

and replace it with

```
<rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="white"/>
```

To set colour of buttons as per comment

```
button.carousel-control-prev,
button.carousel-control-next {
  background-color :white !important;
  color:black;
  opacity: 1;
}

.carousel-control-prev-icon {
   background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 16 16' fill='%23000' %3e%3cpath d='M11.354 1.646a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .708L5.707 8l5.647 5.646a.5.5 0 0 1-.708.708l-6-6a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.708l6-6a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0z'/%3e%3c/svg%3e");
}

.carousel-control-next-icon {
    background-image:url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 16 16' fill='%23000' %3e%3cpath d='M4.646 1.646a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0l6 6a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .708l-6 6a.5.5 0 0 1-.708-.708L10.293 8 4.646 2.354a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.708z'/%3e%3c/svg%3e")
 }
```